# Beaglebone Green SPI Communication

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, beagleboneblack, spi

I've got a little trouble getting the SPI to work on the Beagle Bone green. 
First, I'm running version 4.4.9 of the kernel.

```
xgate@beaglebone:~/spitest$ uname -a
Linux beaglebone 4.4.9-ti-r25 #1 SMP Thu May 5 23:08:13 UTC 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Now, I did add the SPIDEV0 configuration to /sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/slots:

```
xgate@beaglebone:/lib/firmware$ echo BB-SPIDEV0 > /sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/slots 
xgate@beaglebone:~/spitest$ cat /sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/slots
0: PF----  -1
1: PF----  -1
2: PF----  -1
3: PF----  -1
4: P-O-L-   0 Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,BB-SPIDEV0
5: P-O-L-   1 Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,BB-SPIDEV1
```

Now when I open /dev/spi1.0, which should be the SPI0 on the P9 header with the SPI0_CS0, and write to the file using the linux write() function, nothing happens on the pins (I tried communicating with a SPI device, also my logic analyser shows that nothing is happening).

Am I missing something here? I'm struggeling with it for quite a while now and it suprises me that there is not so much to find about. Makes me think I'm just very unlucky that it does not work.

Can anyone please enlighten me about this?
Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: 
Seeing that it's unclear how i tested it, this is the program i used to test the SPI:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int fd;
    unsigned char buf = 0xA1;

    fd = open("/dev/spidev1.0", O_RDWR);
    if(fd < 0) printf("spi failed to open\n");

    while(1)
    {
        write(fd,&buf,1);
    }

    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT2: Fixed! The problem was solved by adding this line to /boot/uEnv.txt:

```
cape_enable=bone_capemgr.enable_partno=BB-SPIDEV0
```

Apparently the SPI does not work when it is added manually to slots after boot.

Comment: Try using the [spidev_test.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/spi/spidev_test.c?v=4.4) program.